# Как отредактировать emb сообщение после нажатие на кнопку nexcord?

Tags: python, discord

```
@nextcord.ui.button(label="Подписаться",style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple) # or .primary
    async def blurple_button(self,button:nextcord.ui.Button,interaction:nextcord.Interaction):
        button.disabled=False
        await interaction.response.send_message('Hi', view=self)
```

Я хочу чтоб при нажатии на кнопку в emb сообщение появлялся ник прожавшего, как это реализовать?
Пока способен только на такой код(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@nextcord.ui.button(label="Подписаться",style=nextcord.ButtonStyle.blurple) # or .primary
    async def blurple_button(self,button:nextcord.ui.Button,interaction:nextcord.Interaction):
        button.disabled=False
        msg = await interaction.response.send_message('Hi')
        await msg.edit('новое сообщение')
```